# Spinner no me muestra texto al seleccionar elemento

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un Dialog con varios elementos dentro, uno de ellos es un spinner, el cual inicializo y le cargo los datos de un ArrayList:

```
public class DialogGArticulos extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_articulos, null);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parentView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerfamilias);
    ListView listView = (ListView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.listaArticulos);

    builder.setView(parentView);


    ArrayList listaFamilias = new ArrayList(Utility.dbHelper.getAllFamiliesAndGroups());

    Log.i("DialogDArticulos","listaFamilias "+ listaFamilias);
    ArrayAdapter adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Utility.dbHelper.getAllFamiliesAndGroups());
    adapterSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);
    spinner.setSelection(0);
return builder.create();
}
```

}

Al lanzar el Dialog, el spinner no muestra nungun texto, pincho en el spinner y me aparecen todas las opciones que he cargado pero al seleccionar una no me aparece el texto en el spinner cerrado, me aparece vacio.

Alguien sabe a que se debe?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba con el getSelectedItem:

```
spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: Al sacar esa información por log me saca el primer valor del spinner, por lo que creo que que tiene el mismo color el texto que el fondo, probare cambiando el xml del item del spinner

Comment: En efecto era eso, al cambiar el xml me ha funcionado.